# smtpauthenticationerror 534 django python registration

Tags: python, django, email, heroku, django-registration

I know that this question was asked a lot o times, but I have a little different situation. I am deploying my django app with implemented django-registration-redux on heroku. The registration works fine on local machine, but it gives smtpauthenticationerror 534 on heroku.

I ALLOWED less secure apps on my google account, but the error persist.

I clicked on [DisplayUnlockCaptcha](https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha) the button Continue- still doesn't work.

Here is the relevant part of settings.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'example@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'domain <example@gmail.com>'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. perhaps did you find the solution?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like google banned the usage of it's accounts for automatic email-sending. The best choice in this case is just to use another service or create an email service [by yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/email/)

Comment: I don't really understand something : if Google banned automatic email sending, how and why does this still work on local machines ?

Comment: is this the case?